# matplotlib display accented characters in Computer Modern

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, diacritics

I want use font typ Computer Modern for text on a figure. But the accented characters, such as ä, ü, can not be displayed. If i use the default font *DejaVu Sans*, it works without any problems. Does anybody know how to solve this? Many thanks.

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = 'cmss10'


    ax.legend(
        [l1, l2, l3], 
        [str(format(int(center_df.Mietfläche.min()), ',d'))+' m$^2$', 
        str(format(int(center_df.Mietfläche.median()), ',d'))+' m$^2$', 
        str(format(int(center_df.Mietfläche.max()), ',d'))+' m$^2$'],
        loc='right',
        bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 0.2),
        fontsize=10,
        labelspacing=1.1,
        title=u'Mietfläche:   ',
        title_fontsize=11,
        frameon=False
        )
```

output with code above:

[image]

output with Tex syntax `$\ddot{a}$`:

[image]

Comment: As a somewhat random idea: did you try \"a instead of ä? (and similar, using TeX syntax)?

Comment: I found https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/computer-modern and it shows the usual glyphs available

Comment: I tried $\ddot{a}$. It comes out ä with umlaut. But it comes out with a total different font typ.

Comment: yes, i have download  fontsquirrel.com/fonts/computer-modern for ms office. It works well for Word. And I tried this with mpl `myfont = mpl.font_manager.FontProperties(fname=r'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\cmss10.ttf')`. Here i have the same problem.

Comment: [output with TeX syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoOGk.png)

Comment: The version of Computer Modern that ships with matplotlib is a legacy 8-bit font, not a Unicode fonts. You'd need to use an alternative version of Computer Modern. Maybe CMU, Latin Modern, or New Computer Modern.